# Regex getting the G, H, D with the 2 numbers before

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a letter and it's numbers before. But regex isn't working as I would think.

Wat might be wrong?

regex: `/(\d{1,2}G|H|D)/g`

inputs:

```
Zddsad 5G (25)
Gtest 5D
DTest 2H
```

expected output:

```
5G
5D
2H
```

actual output:

```
5G
D
D
H
```

running example: regexr.com/4mhab

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to capture? All digit-letter pairs?

Comment: Maybe `\d{1,2}(?:G|H|D)`?

Comment: Because your or `|` don't each include the `\d{1,2}`. Try `\d{1,2}[GHD]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[]`) and not [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`):

```
/(\d{1,2}[GHD])/g
```

If you want to use alternation, you need a group:

```
/(\d{1,2}(G|H|D))/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You get those results because you match either 1 or 2 digits followed by G, or only H or only D.

You don't need a capturing group to get you matches, but you could use a character class and word boundaries `\b` to prevent the matches being part of a larger word.

```
\b\d{1,2}[GHD]\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b3N68j/1)